# На каком диалекте говорит моя дочь?

Tags: диалекты

Помогите разобраться, на каком диалекте говорит моя дочь.
Она говорит:
*Дай мне ручку краснаю* (вместо красную).
*Хочу конфету новаю* (вместо новую).

Comment: На чьем? На своем, дочерином. Вопрос несколько странный. Во-первых, диалект не может принадлежать одному человеку. Во-вторых, если бы Вы даже спросили "на каком", то это было бы неверно по сути. Диалект может впитаться только при пребывании в социальной среде распространения этого диалекта, т.е. впрямую от носителей.  А у дочери вашей либо искусственное искажение речи (наподобие детского кривляния или сюсюканья), либо что-то впитанное в детсаду, школе... Возможно от учительницы или воспитательницы. Это максимум - акцент, никак не диалект.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, мне совершенно непонятно, почему вы принимаете такие окончания за какой-либо диалект. Это ведь ребенок, который может ошибаться, у которого речь ещё не поставлена и т.д. И во-вторых, вы из Киева. Это тоже очень важно: у вас там русский язык совсем другой.

Comment: Мне тоже видится, что это на каком-то наречии, потому как слышал такие выражения от взрослых людей, которые были далеко не потенциальными клиентами логопедов.

Comment: Tagirix, Киев тут никаким боком. Там вокализмы очень четкие. Если уж на что и похоже, так на какой-то рязанско-тамбовский говор... Но дело даже не в этом. По одной фонетической особенности ни говор, ни тем более - диалект ну никак не определяется.